# Storing Objects with Functions in Redux + Local Storage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I currently have 2 class components, the one represents a background worker item - the other the parent component that keeps track of all the items themselves.

For my `BackgroundWorkerItem` I have the following props:

```
export interface WorkerItem {
   id: string;
   createdTime: Date;
   workerType: string;
   onConditionMet: (obj: any) => void;
   object?: any;
   timeoutInterval?: number;
   conditionalCheck?: (obj: any, onConditionMet: (obj: any) => void) => Promise<boolean>;
}
```

Currently, I use `redux` to keep track of all my `WorkerItem`s - the requirement here is that these workers keep doing their processing/polling/timeout check even away from the component where they were fired off (and also kept in local storage in the case the user closes the browser) - but as you can see we should be able to specify a `onConditionMet` function which depending on the worker (as this could be different) is a piece of custom logic that gets fired off when the worker either reaches the timeout value or if the `conditionalCheck` returns the end of its lifecycle.

Obviously, I can't just throw in an object into redux and store it in local storage with a function (and currently it just returns `undefined` which is expected behaviour for both `onConditionMet` and `conditionalCheck`).

I'm wondering given that per `workerType` those two functions will be different if this is a rare case where I say screw it and serialize the function itself manually - or should I rather go the route of using middleware to solve this issue?

If I need to use middleware/enhances/action mappings etc - is there a nice example that goes through something like I'm trying to do? I'm just not wrapping my head around the concept properly at this point.

Comment: If these function can be generated based on the properties of the worker (`workerType`, etc) then I would store a raw object with just the data of the worker.  When you pull the data from redux you can construct it into a full object.

Comment: I think my problem is envisioning how I construct which worker item gets which function to fire off - I can definitely leverage the `workerType` to perhaps find it from a list of actions... But the HOW to do that is where I am kind of stuck...

Comment: If you could share the two components that are creating these workers that would help me understand your use case.  But I'm going to go ahead and write an answer that's more boilerplate for "this type of thing".

Comment: Well now I'm not confident enough to write a boilerplate because I'm not sure what varies based on the *type* of the worker and what varies based on the *instance* of each type.